# ActiveX not running on IE 11

Tags: activex, internet-explorer-11

I've an ActiveX that runs well on IE previous 11 version.

```html
<OBJECT id="DSV" 
        classid="clsid:CBBABF03-D183-11D2-819C-00001C011F1D" 
        align="baseline" 
        border="0" 
        width="0" height="0">
</OBJECT>
```

On Windows 8.1 with IE11, it works only if I launch IE as "administrator".
User is logged in Windows with administrator profile.

All ActiveX security settings are done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would check to see if Protected Mode is breaking it (since elevating IE also get you out of Protected Mode) - try adding it to Trusted Sites and see if that works. If not, then to investigate, I would start with Process Monitor to determine if it's something straightforward, like a file or registry write. You also should consider what the control does in determining what the best course of action would be.